# I want to remove out Strings from an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, any

this is my code

```
func filterString(array:[Any])-> [Int]{
    
    return array.remove(String)
    
    
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@valsamiselmaliotis/removing-specific-type-from-an-array-in-swift-4d45f40eebc5

Answer (score 0):

```
func filterString(array:[Any])-> [Any]{
        var finalArr : [Any] = []
        for i in array{
            if i is String.Type == false{
                finalArr.append(i)
            }
        }
        return finalArr
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter should be enough

```
var arr: [Any] = ["", "", 1, 2.5]
print(arr.filter({ $0 is Int }))
// print [1]
```

This will return an array of Int as you seem to search for in your code. But you can also filter on only removing strings, leaving rest intact:

```
var arr: [Any] = ["", "", 1, 2.5]
print(arr.filter({ !($0 is String) }))
// print [1, 2.5]
```

And with your function:

```
func filterString(array: [Any]) -> [Int]{
    array.filter { $0 is Int } as? [Int] ?? []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost

```
var array : [Any] = [1, "one", 2, "two", 3, "three"]
array.removeAll(where: {$0 is String})
```

or with your function, consistently you have to remove everything which is not `Int`

```
func filterString(array: [Any]) -> [Int]{
    var temp = array
    temp.removeAll(where: {$0 is Int == false})
    return temp as! [Int]
}
```

Another way is `compactMap`

```
func filterString(array: [Any]) -> [Int]{
    return array.compactMap{$0 as? Int}
}
```